# .NET framework version requirement

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is there any way for a web user to determine the version of the .NET framework that is required for a particular web page they are viewing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is possible. It is the website owner who chooses which framework the application will be using (in IIS) More over some functions which are valid in .net 1.1. are no longer valid in 3.5 so this if something  like this exists then the application will not work.

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET web pages are processed at the server, and just send plain HTML to the browser.  There is no requirement for the client to have the .NET Framework on their pc when viewing webpages created with ASP.NET.  The server needs to have the correct version of the .NET Framework installed to process the page however.

In the case of server side, with the exception of Visual Studio 2008, all versions of VS are tied to a specific version of the framework.

Visual Studio.NET (2002) => .NET Framework 1.0
Visual Studio.NET 2003 => .NET Framework 1.1
Visual Studio.NET 2005 => .NET Framework 2.0

There is a Framework 3.0 which adds Windows Presentation, Communication, and Workflow frameworks, and these applications can be built with Visual Studio 2005 with proper addins installed.  Visual Studio 2008 can target any of the 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 frameworks.

If you are attempting to download an existing project, and are trying to determine which hosts can run the application, then you should check the website of the application you wish to use, and it should give you requirements.  For the most part, the frameworks are backwards compatible, so an application built for 2.0 will run on 3.5.  So you don't need an exact match, however 1.0 and 1.1 applications will not run on a server with only 2.0 or higher installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I misphrased the question, actually. I actually need to know what version of the .NET framework is required on the server to render the page. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

No mechanism for this is intentionally provided.  You might be able to figure out some hack that works under controlled circumstances, but I'm not aware of one personally.